# Obtener el userId de OneSignal en app de IONIC

Tags: app, push-notification, ionic3, onesignal

Necesito acceder al UserId de un componente pushnotification con el plugin de  OneSiganl en una aplicación de Ionic.

El provider donde hago la inicialización se llama en app.component.ts. 
Me crea el servicio sin problema y las notificaciones me llegan.

El problema es que necesito guardar en mi pagina de login el userId que se obtiene con getIds(). Y no se como acceder en mi componente login a ese valor, si tengo que volver a levantar el servicio para poder acceder a ese Id o como hacerlo.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo hice de esta manera, ojalá te sirva:

```
id(){
    if(this.platform.is('cordova')){
      this.oneSignal.getIds().then(res=>{
        console.log(res.userId) . //===>ESTE ES TU ID
        this._us.dispositivo = res.userId;
        //AQUI LO GUARDAS EN TU STORAGE O DB
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: He editado tu respuesta, pero para que tu respuesta sea de calidad que requiere Stack Overflow en Español, debes agregar una descripción de qué hace este código y por qué soluciona el problema del usuario.